# Can I override a method but still use the same arguments as the method from the super class in python?

Tags: python, class

I just wanted to know if there was a way to override a method and still ask for the same arguments. I want to override a method so I can do other stuff before calling the original one, but I still want it to ask for the same arguments and I don't want to have to update all of the child classes when I change the parent class.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x: int = 0
        self.y: int = 0

    def SetPosition(self, position):
        self.x = position[0]
        self.y = position[1]


class Label(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Label, self).__init__()

    def SetPosition(self, position):
        super(Label, self).SetPosition(position)
        # Do something


class TextBox(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TextBox, self).__init__()

    def SetPosition(self, position):
        super(TextBox, self).SetPosition(position)
        # Do something else
```

For example, if I wanted to add another argument to the SetPostion in the Base class, would I have to manually add it to all of the other ones?

I don't want to manually change all of the values every time because I know I will miss some somewhere. I don' want to use *args or **kwargs either.

Comment: It's normal to accept tha same parameters when you override a method. If you don't, you violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without having to copy the parameter list? Use `*args, **kwargs` for generic parameters.

Comment: @Barmar I want to try and not use `*args` or `**kwargs` so you know what the options for the inputs are

Comment: Then you have to hard-code the parameter lists and the calls to `super()`. Which means you'll have to update the subclasses if you change the superclass.